# How can I mark my question as a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked a question knowing that it is a duplicate, because I was not satisfied with the accepted (and only) answer of the original question. After some answers and discussion in my question, I understood the original question better, and added an answer to the original question myself providing my insight. How can I now close my question as a duplicate? I don't think I have rights to mark questions as duplicates.

I could answer my own question, pointing to the duplicate, but I don't think this is right.

Comment: You can flag your question for duplicate or bring to moderator attention or socvr chat room.

Comment: You don't have that option to close the question and mark it as a duplicate. You can flag it. There is _a duplicate..._ checkbox and hit that.

Comment: since you have over 15 rep points [recipe like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773) might work: 1. Flag to close as duplicate 2. Refresh question in browser to make new duplicate prompt appear 3. Click the big blue button ("That solved my problem!"), the question will instantly close

Comment: @gnat Thank you.  I did that.  I also accepted the answer to my duplicate question that had the most useful information.

Answer (score 13):

At the bottom of your question, you should see an option to flag it. You can then click the **Should be closed..** radio button option and pick the first reason: **Duplicate of...** and paste in the URL or title of the question yours duplicates.

This will send your question to the Close Vote Review Queue where others can act upon it by voting to close it for any reason, including the one you recommended, or by disagreeing and voting to leave the question open.

Once you have 3,000 reputation, you can do this more directly by casting an actual close vote of your own. This will still send it to the CV Review Queue, but it will already have one close vote on it.

Questions need a minimum of five close votes to be closed, and a maximum of ten, depending on the score of the question. Exceptions are:

- When a moderator closes your question
- When someone with a gold tag badge of one of your question's tags (in, say [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers)) votes to close your question as a duplicate, they can do so unilaterally via a trusted site privilege.
- When someone else votes to close your question as a duplicate first, and you agree with the system prompt asking if it is actually a duplicate.

In each of these three situations, when the action is performed, the question will instantly be closed.

Comment: In gnat's comment, they mention that you could flag, refresh, then insta-close your question. Wouldn't that be another exception? Also, wouldn't that be a better way?