# What should I do if I found an answer to my question on another post?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53278323/2675154) and then found that my problem was resolved in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34858989/2675154). How can I close my question as a duplicate? Or should I just add a response providing the link to the Q&A and an example?

Comment: Either vote to close your question as a duplicate or simply delete it if it doesn't add anything new.

Comment: Either way, I've hammered it as a duplicate.

Comment: I will say, PROPS for continuing your research and finding a duplicate, then trying to follow the site's rules by having it closed properly :).

Comment: @BDL: You can't vote to close your own question until you have 250 rep. (I think you can still flag it for closure, though.)

Comment: @BoltClock You can flag your own post for closure as a duplicate, then get the _does this answer your question_ prompt, accept that, and unilaterally close the question without any required rep afaik.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth good to know for the next time, maybe submit it as an answer to close that subject?

Comment: @Shas you can try it for yourself, I just found a duplicate of this question: [How can I mark my question as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364513/7795130). Try copying that link `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364513/7795130` into the flag as duplicate dialog and see if it works.

Comment: this is starting to get even more meta  in there :v
edit: i try, but, i can't put it as a duplicate myself, i need somone to validate it

Comment: Ok, cool, that's good to know. But now that you've flagged it, it'll get closed in a little bit