# Why can't I insta-mark my own question as a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[How can I mark my question as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364513/how-can-i-mark-my-question-as-a-duplicate) shows that marking my own question as a dupe is no different than marking someone else's.

But why can't I just decide? As the author I might be far better placed to realise another question already answers my problem, since I know what I was *trying* to ask... sometimes it is hard to express exactly what a question is, until you see another question/asnwer.

Maybe there are several suggestions for which question I am duping, and I want to make sure the correct one is selected.

Have I missed some additional feature? Maybe moderators can see the author's dupe-flag more prominently or something?

Comment: You can, when someone else starts the close process. Then you can accept the duplicate and your question will be closed instantly. Or when you have a gold badge, when it hammer the question.

Comment: In short, you can; cast a close vote yourself and then the process [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/566903) will kick in, allowing you to complete the closure.

Comment: Just in case this was missed, you need to refresh the page first after voting to close as a dupe for the banner to appear.